# Resources causing transparent and erratic window behavior VB.net 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, textbox, transparent

I'm not entirely sure what caused this, but just prior I had deleted an image that was set as a tab panels background image which caused some crashing of vb studio when opening anything to do with the project resources. I removed the image, then re-added it and everything seemed okay.

Now, no mater what I do i get all sorts of funky draw issues at runtime with my project; such as transparent text boxes in child forms (and if they are called not as a MDI child) and weird stuff such as clicks on the taskbar registering on windows behind.

Visual studio has also crashed a few times, especially when doing anything to do with the project resources.

[Example Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyuIT.jpg)

Any one have idea what may be causing this? It seems to be related to the project resources or possibly tab panels.

(Visual Studio 2012 & Windows 10)

Comment: I have just found that the form in the example picture works fine if its a MDI child, but as a separate dialog the behavior returns.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody finds this Question after all this time. I had the same Problem and i found, that the Transparency-Key of my form was set to White, so everything White became transparent (Textboxes, colored Labels, etc.). After deleting that, everything worked fine.

I use Visual Studio 2013, don't know if this doesn't work in the 2012 Version.

Comment: My problem seemed to act the same but I had checked that. I ended up moving to vs 2015 and after rebuilding the project it was fine. Never found the actual cause.